# Beta Binomial Function in Python

Tags: python, distribution, probability-density, binomial-cdf

I would like to calculate the probability given by a binomial distribution for predetermined x(successes), n(trials), and p(probability) - the later of which is given by a probability mass function Beta(a,b).

I am aware of `scipy.stats.binom.pmf(x,n,p)` - but I am unsure how I can replace p with a probability function. I am also wondering whether I could use the `loc` argument of  [`scipy.stats.binom.pmf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html) to emulate this behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Beta-binomial_distribution_as_a_compound_distribution) that the compound distribution function is given by

```
f(k|n,a,b) = comb(n,k) * B(k+a, n-k+b) / B(a,b)
```

where B is the beta function, a and b are the original Beta parameters and n is the Binomial one. k here is your x and p disappears because you integrate over the values of p to obtain this (convolution).
That is, you won't find it in scipy but it is a one-liner provided you have [the beta function from scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.beta.html#scipy.special.beta).

Comment: is choose supposed to return an integer (I guess so, but [`numpy.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) seems to return an array).

Comment: Yes, choose is a combination, look there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Ok, so maybe then you mean [comb](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html), not [choose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html)? am I right to use [`scipy.misc.comb`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) for that?

Comment: Yes `scipy.misc.comb`. But many call it "n choose k". I'll update the answer with `comb`.

Comment: Also the beta function B is `scipy.special.beta`.

Comment: For future reference, [here is a very nice blog post](http://www.channelgrubb.com/blog/2015/2/27/beta-binomial-in-python) that gives a Python function for the beta-binomial PMF that still works well for large `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 10):

If your values of `n` (total # trials) and `x` (# successes) are large, then a more stable way to compute the beta-binomial probability is by working with logs. Using the [gamma function expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Beta-binomial_distribution_as_a_compound_distribution) of the beta-binomial distribution function, the natural log of your desired probability is:

```
ln(answer) = gammaln(n+1) + gammaln(x+a) + gammaln(n-x+b) + gammaln(a+b) - \
        (gammaln(x+1) + gammaln(n-x+1) + gammaln(a) + gammaln(b) + gammaln(n+a+b))
```

where [`gammaln`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaln.html) is the natural log of the gamma function, given in `scipy.special`.

(BTW: The `loc` argument just shifts the distribution left or right, which is not what you want here.)

Answer (score 0):

The Beta-Binomial distribution is included in scipy from version 1.4.0 as [scipy.stats.betabinom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.4.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.betabinom.html)