# Trouble with Scipy.Minimize including bounds

Tags: python, r, scipy

I want to minimize the negative loglikelihood in order to approach an earlier calculated distribution as closely as possible. My distribution is a Beta-Binomial distribution and I need to pick the *a (lpha)* and *b(eta)* parameters. I based my function that calculates the negative loglikelihood on one of the answers of another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935127/beta-binomial-function-in-python).

```
def nll(a, b):
    k = players['Goals'].sum() # equal to the number of successes
    n = players['Shots'].sum() # equal to the number of trials
    log = gammaln(n + 1) + gammaln(k + a) + gammaln(n - k + b) + gammaln(a + b) - (gammaln(k + 1) + gammaln(n - k + 1) + gammaln(a) + gammaln(b) + gammaln(n + a + b))
    return -(np.exp(log))
```

Next, I want to minimize the loglikelihood. In R this can be done with the following script:

```
# maximum likelihood estimation
m <- mle(ll, start = list(alpha = 1, beta = 10), 
method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0.0001, 0.1))

ab <- coef(m)
```

I am trying to reproduce the R-script in Python as follows:

```
 init_params = [1, 10] # This is equal to the start-argument in R

 res = minimize(nll, x0=init_params, method='L-BFGS-B', options={'disp' : True, 'maxiter': 250})
```

Running this, yields the following error:

**return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
TypeError: nll() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'**

What am I exactly doing wrong? I inserted b=10 right?

Answer (score 0):

`optimize.minimize` expects its first argument to be a function of this form:

```
def func(params, args):
    ...
```

where `params` represents all the parameters `optimize.minimize` is trying to minimize. `args` can be used to pass additional arguments which are not  to be minimized over; they are essentially constants as far as `optimize.minimize` is concerned.

In this case `params` represents two values, `a` and `b`, so write `nll` like this:

```
def nll(params):
    a, b = params
    ...
```