# Finding alpha and beta of beta-binomial distribution with scipy.optimize and loglikelihood

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, beta, binomial-theorem

A distribution is beta-binomial if *p*, the probability of success, in a binomial distribution has a beta distribution with shape parameters *α > 0* and *β > 0*. The shape parameters define the probability of success.
I want to find the values for *α* and *β* that best describe my data from the perspective of a beta-binomial distribution. My dataset `players`  consist of data about the number of hits (*H*), the number of at-bats (*AB*) and the conversion (*H / AB*) of a lot of baseball players. I estimate the PDF with the help of the answer of JulienD in [Beta Binomial Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935127/beta-binomial-function-in-python)

```
from scipy.special import beta
from scipy.misc import comb

pdf = comb(n, k) * beta(k + a, n - k + b) / beta(a, b)
```

Next, I write a loglikelihood function that we will minimize.

```
def loglike_betabinom(params, *args):
   """
   Negative log likelihood function for betabinomial distribution
   :param params: list for parameters to be fitted.
   :param args:  2-element array containing the sample data.
   :return: negative log-likelihood to be minimized.
   """

   a, b = params[0], params[1]
   k = args[0] # the conversion rate
   n = args[1] # the number of at-bats (AE)

   pdf = comb(n, k) * beta(k + a, n - k + b) / beta(a, b)

   return -1 * np.log(pdf).sum()
```

Now, I want to write a function that minimizes *loglike_betabinom*

```
 from scipy.optimize import minimize
 init_params = [1, 10]
 res = minimize(loglike_betabinom, x0=init_params,
                args=(players['H'] / players['AB'], players['AB']),
                bounds=bounds,
                method='L-BFGS-B',
                options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 250})
 print(res.x)
```

The result is [-6.04544138  2.03984464], which implies that α is negative which is not possible. I based my script on the following R-snippet. They get [101.359, 287.318]..

```
 ll <- function(alpha, beta) { 
    x <- career_filtered$H
    total <- career_filtered$AB
    -sum(VGAM::dbetabinom.ab(x, total, alpha, beta, log=True))
 }

 m <- mle(ll, start = list(alpha = 1, beta = 10), 
 method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0.0001, 0.1))

 ab <- coef(m)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Help is much appreciated!!

Comment: How are you minimizing your loss function now? Did you write your own method, or are you using something from a package? Either way, what are the details?

Comment: I use `from scipy.optimize import minimize`

Comment: @HJA24 What is `players`? Can you share that data please? That is the missing part for me to test my answer.

Comment: Where do you specify your `bounds` that you are passing in to `minimize`?

Comment: I removed the bounds-part

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vFYzyJcPbDYRLP_AaWGQ5QFw9KCAcUgP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing to pay attention to is that `comb(n, k)` in your log-likelihood might not be well-behaved numerically for the values of `n` and `k` in your dataset. You can verify this by applying `comb` to your data and see if `inf`s appear.

One way to amend things could be to rewrite the negative log-likelihood as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32355701/4240413, i.e. as a function of logarithms of Gamma functions as in

```
from scipy.special import gammaln
import numpy as np

def loglike_betabinom(params, *args):

    a, b = params[0], params[1]
    k = args[0] # the OVERALL conversions
    n = args[1] # the number of at-bats (AE)

    logpdf = gammaln(n+1) + gammaln(k+a) + gammaln(n-k+b) + gammaln(a+b) - \
     (gammaln(k+1) + gammaln(n-k+1) + gammaln(a) + gammaln(b) + gammaln(n+a+b))

    return -np.sum(logpdf)
```

You can then minimize the log-likelihood with

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

init_params = [1, 10]
# note that I am putting 'H' in the args
res = minimize(loglike_betabinom, x0=init_params,
            args=(players['H'], players['AB']),
            method='L-BFGS-B', options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 250})
print(res)
```

and that should give reasonable results.

You could check [How to properly fit a beta distribution in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329331/how-to-properly-fit-a-beta-distribution-in-python) for inspiration if you want to rework further your code.